# SQL Server 2008 R2 - Select ntext as XML

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

How can I convert a large chunk of XML from an NTEXT column into typed XML on 2008R2.

```
SELECT CAST(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), [Parameters]) AS XML) AS Parameters
FROM Subscriptions
WHERE DATALENGTH(Parameters) > 8000;
```

Throws an error

```
Msg 9400, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
XML parsing: line 1, character 8000, unexpected end of input
```

A typical row looks like this ( but bigger, no XML header or encoding info )

```
<ParameterValues>
   <ParameterValue><Name>Subscription</Name><Value>1</Value></ParameterValue>
</ParameterValues>
```

I've tried temp tables, CONVERT and CAST in various combinations without success. Any suggestions much appreciated.

@@VERSION = "Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP2) - 10.50.4000.0 (X64)   Jun 28 2012 08:36:30   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1  (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (Hypervisor) "

Comment: Doh, it's a misleading error message. Nothing to do with the size, one row had some badly formed XML.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I found two ways to do that and tested on 2012. its working fine

```
Create table Subscriptions (Parameters VARCHAR(MAX) )     

DECLARE @Fill VARCHAR(MAX)     

SET @Fill = REPLICATE('A',10000)     

insert into Subscriptions      
select @Fill     

/***Option 1 :** */      
SELECT CAST('<r>'+ Parameters +'</r>' AS XML) from Subscriptions
    --(1 row(s) affected)

/***Option2:***/     

Declare @text NVarchar(max)     

Declare @x xml     

SELECT @text = Parameters      

FROM Subscriptions     

select @text     

Set @x =N'<root>
    <item>1</item><item>1</item><item>1</item><item>1</item><item>1</item><item>'+@text+N'</item><item>1</item><item>1</item><item>1</item><item>1</item>
</root>
'      

Select @x
```

Comment: Thanks, but the source column is NTEXT not varchar

Comment: @emailgregn then cast it as nvarchar(max) or better change the column to nvarchar(max). ntext is depricated

Comment: Thanks for editing and mark in code, not sure why its not working for me. And i tested in 2014 evealuation edition not 2012

Answer (score 0):

You can try one more way , this is working for ntext as well

```sql
SELECT  Parameters  from Subscriptions FOR XML RAW
```

I just verified , user was correct it could be  bad xml. did bit more testing and found

```sql
SELECT  Parameters  from Subscriptions FOR XML RAW  
/*retourns all rows in 1 xml*/   

SELECT CAST(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), [Parameters]) AS XML) AS Parameters
```

FROM Subscriptions
    /*Returns every row as xml*/

Refrence : SQL server tecnet refrence:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522623.aspx

Comment: Your post has been flagged as low quality, but as you're new on SO, I'm not voting for deletion, instead, could you explain to the OP and the other readers what your line of SQL does and why this would help the OP solve his problem? Thank You!